# Get name of a form submit button Django

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have an array of forms. When the user click to submit one of those forms i want identify which one he decided to submit.
So I have an array of names to name all my submit buttons :

```
{% for n in db %}
    ...
    <input type = 'submit' name = '{{ n.movie_id }}' value = 'ok' />
{% endfor %}`
```

I'd like to get this name in my view to create objects in my database.
Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: I think that you should just add a hidden field which his value is the form id

Comment: Great idea, it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Coming to this late, I know, but you can solve this problem using a button rather than an input.

```
<button type="submit" name="button1" value="button1press" > Submit </button>
```

Coincidentally available to me while debugging something else ... Django sees

```
self.request.POST { 'button1': 'button1press', ... }
```